# How to secure an API

Tags: asp.net, json, ssl

I am developing an API as a middleman between a Windows app and the database. The webserver will just be an ASP. NET generic handler returning json.
Users will log into the app and their credentials will be transmitted over the wire. From there what I was going to do was generate a session key that the app could use from then on with every request.
This will not be an open API in the foreseeable future. 
Now what I am wondering is if this is secure enough? How can I stop people from using fiddler to just replicate the calls?
Is there a better approach to this? Would it help if I used SSL?

I don't want to complicate matters by using oauth.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SSL. In order to obtain the session token the client should authenticate himself with a username and password transmitted over SSL. Once authenticated the token should be transmitted to the server over SSL to prevent from man-in-the-middle attacks.

So here's the flow:

1. The client sends his credentials (username and password) over SSL to a web method
2. The web method verifies the credentials and generates a session token and returns this session token to the client.
3. The client sends the session token on subsequent requests to protected resources.
4. The server verifies the token and if valid grants access to the protected resource.

You use simple [Forms Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx) to generate the session tokens. The [FormsAuthentication.Encrypt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.encrypt.aspx) and [FormsAuthentication.Decrypt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.decrypt.aspx) methods could be a good start for you. The forms authentication token contains an encrypted value of the currently authenticated user. If you are running in a web-farm make sure that you have static [machine keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649308.aspx) on all nodes of your web farm, otherwise a session token encrypted on one node might not be decrypted on another node.

As an alternative to session tokens you could use [basic authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) over SSL. The drawback is that credentials are sent over the wire on each request. Even if you are using SSL, the password is still transmitted over the wire, so this method is less secure than session tokens but easier to setup.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!
One problem though is that I don't have control over the database. I will be connecting to an existing MySQL database and cannot change the schema. Now as far as I remember (I've been out of ASP dev for ages), to implement ASP.NET forms auth you either need to use their schema or write a custom implementation. The latter would be overcomplicating it once again.

Is there any problem of just making my own way of creating a session key? Like hashing the username and some other variables?

Comment: @Matt, Forms Authentication has strictly nothing to do with any databases or schemas. You seem to be confusing Forms Authentication with the Membership Provider which are 2 completely different notions. You could perfectly fine use FA with Membership and Membership without FA. So in your case all you need to do is to check the username and password against your database (whatever this database is) and then call the Encrypt method to generate the key and return to the user either as a cookie or a custom header. Hashing the username will be of no use in your case because ...

Comment: ... hashing is a non-reversible process. This means that if you give the user this hash and he subsequently sends it to you on another request you have no way of knowing who is the user, unless you have stored those hashes in your database. FA on the other hand is stateless. It uses encryption (not hashing).

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I was confusing the two - and your post makes total sense now. 
Thanks for the help!